# Simplest way to turn a covariance table into a covariance matrix in numpy

Tags: numpy

Say you load in a table of correlations that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 1], ['B', 'C', 2], ['A', 'C', 3], ['C', 'D', 100]])
```

1 is the covariance between A and B, 2 is the covariance between B and C, etc.

What's the most elegant (readable + efficient) way to convert this to:

```
np.array([[1, 1, 3, 0], [1, 1, 2, 0], [3, 2, 1, 100], [0, 0, 100, 1]])
```

The full covariance matrix for A, B, C, and D, assuming that unwritten relationships are 0 (true in my case). Variables can be in any order.

Comment: I don't think having a ndarray with string and numbers at the same time is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I mention in a comment, having a `ndarray` with strign and numbers will convert all to strings. So you must convert back to float the values of correlation in the first table.

Assuming you have the first table like this:

```py
correlations = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [2, 3, 100])
```

Where `'A'` is 0, `'B'` is 1, and so on...

you can create the matrix you need like this:

```py
matrix = np.identity(var_counts)
for correlation in correlations:
    i, j, value = correlation
    i, j = int(i), int(j)
    matrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i] = value
```

Where `var_counts` is the number of variables you have in the first table.